# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() mistake in sql query

Tags: php, pagination

So I am working on a pagination system in php, I got to the part where I get all the posts from the database using sql this is my code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent="0" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page';
$articles = $db->query($sql);
```

$start should be set to 0 and $per_page to 20

But when running the result through a foreach loop it returns this warning:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\System-tips\index.php on line 29
>   Call Stack

when manualy entering the numbers in the sql query it works perfectly, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: here is the full index.php code

```
<?php
include"header.php";

//Delete Auto Draft posts
$del = 'DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title="Auto Draft"';
$db->query($del);

//Receive all posts
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent="0" ORDER BY ID DESC';
$counter = $db->query($sql);

//Amount of pages
$row_cnt = $counter->num_rows;
$per_page = 5;
$pages = ceil($row_cnt/$per_page);

//Receive current page
if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
header("location: index.php?page=1");
}
else {
$page = $_GET['page'];
}

$start = (($page - 1)*$per_page);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent="0" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page';
$articles = $db->query($sql);

foreach ($articles as $article) {
echo'
<article>
<h3>'. $article['post_title'] .'</h3>';
search_picture($article['post_content']);
preview($article['post_content']);
echo '<a href="#">Read the article...</a>';
echo'</article>';

}

function search_picture($content) {
$array = explode('<img',$content);
if (isset($array[1])) {
$picture = explode(' />',$array[1]);
echo '<img' . $picture[0] . ' />'; }
echo '
<style>
img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}</style>
';
}

function preview($content) {
$preview = explode('<!--more-->',$content);
echo '<p style="margin-right: 20px;">' . $preview[0] . '</p>';
}

include"footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: Post the `index.php` foreach.

Comment: Can you post the result (or partial if it's too large) of `var_dump($articles);`?

Comment: var_dump returns: boolean false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but your string here:

```
'SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent="0" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page'
```

... is enclosed in `'` single quotes. PHP being PHP, interpolation such as you have here will only work if the string is enclosed in `"` double quotes. So, as a first step, try switching your `"`s with your `'`s.

Comment: No problem at all :) It's basically to do with how strings within `"`s are evaluated compared to `'`. There is a slight performance difference between interpolation and concatenation, sometimes one is more suitable than the other :)